# Emails sorted which not have thread

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

i use mh mailclient and now i have buy new laptop. My Emails are more then 10 GB and when i sync with new laptop where a nice idea make the directory clean.

My idea is delete all mails, which have no thread. When i saw the files without thread so is missing the References: and In-Reply-To: in header. I think when search all files without References and In-Reply-To in header and without follow other files which same subject can be deleted.

Examples:

1.) without thread

```
From: someone
Date: Fri, 13 Feb 2004 10:45:02 +0000
Subject: grub Error 15: File not found
Message-ID: <s02caadf.033@fsldn03.london.int.cre.gov.uk>
```

2.) with thread (first mail)

```
From: someone
Date: Wed, 10 Feb 2016 13:30:50 -0800
Subject: [lfs-support] isl library and ld SEARCH_DIR
Message-ID: <messageid>
```

3.) answer

```
From: bruce.dubbs at gmail.com (Bruce Dubbs)
Date: Wed, 10 Feb 2016 15:57:42 -0600
Subject: [lfs-support] isl library and ld SEARCH_DIR
In-Reply-To: <in-reply-to>
References: <references>
Message-ID: <id>
```

So normal can all deleted without reference and in-reply-to and without same subject. Has someone a idea is has someone written a program in this way? Or has idea how can relized with bash?

Thank you for help
Silvio

Comment: For clarification, you would like a script that would search every email in a folder, and delete all emails that do NOT have "In-Reply-To" and "references"?

Comment: Yes right. I has try with grep and find but want delete more as it should. The Email format is mh, sylpheed and claws mail use this.

Comment: In your example, do you want to keep or delete msg #2?

Comment: One should delete, because no Reply and Reference. But only delete if in other files not same Subject.

Comment: Where are all of yours emails stored? for example **/var/tmp/email/email1 and /var/tmp/email/email2**.

Comment: ,.mail/Maillinglists and there stored in folders for unix, software, webapps etc. Really much folders and files, all together has more than 10 GB. It must not be recursive, only i go in folder, call the script and it run through all files, in some folders more then 1000000 files. I archive all my emails since years. I start with hand but its to much, one folder more then 10000 times press del.

Answer (score -1):

I have little try with find and exec commands. Now have filtered all mails with "In-Reply-To" in header and mv them to other folder.

```
siefke@sisibox ~/Downloads $ ls -l lfs/ | wc -l
48015

find lfs/ -type f -exec grep -q "In-Reply-To" {} \; -exec mv {} reply/ \;
```

Now, the emails have divided as follows.

```
siefke@sisibox ~/Downloads $ ls -l lfs/ | wc -l
17915

siefke@sisibox ~/Downloads $ ls -l reply/ | wc -l
30101
```

Now, it will be difficult. How can I read the subject from files in folder lfs and compare with the files in the folder reply? Is there a hit, the file should move to the folder reply. Then in folder LFS would stand only files that have not reply, no thread.

Has here someone a way?

Nice Day
Silvio